# TFS: Code Review Metrics

Tags: tfs

I want to generate some metrics for measuring the effectiveness of our code review process.

Some of the metrics that I am thinking about is
1. Defect count - Number of defects recorded per code review
2. Percent of code reviewed 
3. Time in review

I am having trouble writing queries that generate these metrics in TFS. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you post your (not working?) queries we'll have a good start point to (try to) fix them.

Comment: Do your coders create bugs when they do a code review and associate that bug with the code review?

Comment: @MrHinsh the just add comments to the code review

Comment: you need to post this to codereview.stackexchange

Comment: Code Review is only for reviewing implemented, working code; not for discussing code review techniques or for writing code.